# Convert LINQ (Entity Framework) nested Any's to take N parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Requirement: check if a list of successive words exists in a dataset. If it does, return a boolean to show the success.

Here is my code so far with unit tests (**note this is sample code only - `DataSet` will be with Entity Framework not just a List**):

```
[Test]
public void PhraseSearch()
{
    var DataSet = new List<Word>
                    {
                        new Word { Text = "First", Sequence = 0 },
                        new Word { Text = "Second", Sequence = 1 },
                        new Word { Text = "Third", Sequence = 2 },
                        new Word { Text = "Forth", Sequence = 3 },
                        new Word { Text = "Five", Sequence = 4 }
                    };

    var goodSearch = new string[]{ "First", "Second", "Third" };
    var badSearch = new string[] { "First", "NOTFOUND", "Third" };

    // successful test for 2 words
    var result = DataSet.Any(wrd1 => wrd1.Text == goodSearch[0] && DataSet.Any(wrd2 => wrd2.Text == goodSearch[1] && wrd2.Sequence == wrd1.Sequence + 1));
    Assert.That(result, Is.True);

     result = DataSet.Any(wrd1 => wrd1.Text == badSearch[0] && 
                DataSet.Any(wrd2 => wrd2.Text == badSearch[1] && wrd2.Sequence == wrd1.Sequence + 1));

    // successful test for 2 words that don't match the data
    Assert.That(result, Is.False);

    // successful test for 3 words
    result = DataSet.Any(wrd1 => wrd1.Text == goodSearch[0] && 
                               DataSet.Any(wrd2 => wrd2.Text == goodSearch[1] && wrd2.Sequence == wrd1.Sequence + 1 && 
                                                 DataSet.Any(wrd3 => wrd3.Text == goodSearch[2] && wrd3.Sequence == wrd2.Sequence + 1)));
    Assert.That(result, Is.True);

    // test for N words
    result = .....
}
```

I want to expand the Linq code to do N words, but i'm not sure how to do this with Linq in Entity Framework, I'm leaning towards a hard coded method for each number of words but that seems really smelly.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Contains`, so something like `list.Any(x => wordList.Contains(x))`

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for taking the time to answer, how would i pass in the sequential sequence to the contains statement?

Comment: @mjwills, no the words will not be unique,

Comment: Does a good search always need to start with `First` or can it start with any word from the dataset as long as the sequence is maintained?

Comment: It looks like you're searching for a sub-sequence of words to be the same. Is that right?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit, the search could also be {"Third, "Fourth"} and I'd want a match

Comment: @Enigmativity, correct, i want the subset to be found

Comment: I think looking up the first match and iterating from there would be better than trying to squeeze this in a LINQ statement.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit, this is coming back from a DbContext where word one could be very common (and, a hello etc), I want to use linq to pass the multiple words through to the DB to save on Db calls.

Comment: If you want to do this on a DbContext, you'll have to dynamically build the LINQ expression.

Comment: Oh, so this is using Entity Framework? That is a completely different question then. You need to be explicit about that requirement.

Comment: Sorry, @WouterHuysentruit and mjwillis , I didn't think it was relevant to the problem, I hoped by excluding that detail it would focus the question

Comment: LINQ to Objects and EF are two completely different things. A solution for L2O won't help you at all for EF (for this specific problem).

Comment: If the list contained `a b c d e f a g h` and you searched for `a g h` would you expect `true` or `false` to be returned (and why) @MrGiggles ?

Comment: @mjwills i would want true returned as the sequence a g h exists in the collection in the correct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following extension which also takes into account that there could be multiple subsets in the longer sequence and a latter one contains the whole seb-sequence:

```
public static bool ContainsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, IEnumerable<T> subSeq, EqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    IList<T> list = subSeq as IList<T> ?? new List<T>(subSeq);
    IEnumerable<int> allIndexes = seq.AllIndexesOf(list.First(), comparer);
    foreach (int index in allIndexes)
    {
        bool containsSequence = seq.Skip(index).Take(list.Count).SequenceEqual(list, comparer);
        if (containsSequence)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using this simple extension to find all indexes:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T itemToFind, EqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    int index = 0;
    foreach (T item in seq)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(itemToFind, item))
            yield return index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Now the remaining check is simple:

```
bool containsSubseq = DataSet.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).Select(x => x.Text)
   .ContainsSequence(goodSearch);
```

However, this works for Linq-To-Objects not for database driven LINQ providers(saw too late).

Comment: @mjwills: fixed it :)

Comment: Would return false, true expected?

Comment: @mjwills: well, my approach still works only for Linq -To-Objects but now checks all subsets not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

I like the subset queries, but i ended up writing a recursive any statement to solve this as below:

```
  public void PhraseSearch()
    {
        var DataSet = new List<Word>
                        {
                            new Word { Text = "First", Sequence = 0 },
                            new Word { Text = "Second", Sequence = 1 },
                            new Word { Text = "Third", Sequence = 2 },
                            new Word { Text = "Forth", Sequence = 3 },
                            new Word { Text = "Five", Sequence = 4 }
                        };

        var goodSearch1 = new[] { "Second" };
        var goodSearch2 = new[] { "First", "Second"};
        var goodSearch3 = new[] {  "Second", "Third", "Forth" };
        var badSearch = new[] { "First", "NOTFOUND", "Third" };

        // successful test for 1 word
        int idxTosearch = 0;
        var result = DataSet.Any(wrd => wrd.Text == goodSearch1[idxTosearch] && NextAny(goodSearch1,idxTosearch + 1,DataSet, wrd));
        Assert.That(result, Is.True);


        //reset counter
        idxTosearch = 0;
        result = DataSet.Any(wrd => wrd.Text == goodSearch2[0] && NextAny(goodSearch2, idxTosearch + 1, DataSet, wrd));

        // successful test for 2 words 
        Assert.That(result, Is.True);

        //reset counter
        idxTosearch = 0;
        // successful test for 3 words
        result = DataSet.Any(wrd => wrd.Text == goodSearch3[0] && NextAny(goodSearch3, idxTosearch + 1, DataSet, wrd));
        Assert.That(result, Is.True);

        // test for bad  words
        //reset counter
        idxTosearch = 0;
        result = DataSet.Any(wrd => wrd.Text == badSearch[0] && NextAny(badSearch, idxTosearch + 1, DataSet, wrd));
        Assert.That(result, Is.False);


    }

 private static bool NextAny(string[] phraseArray, int idxToSearch, List<Word> DataSet, Word previousWord)
    {

        if (idxToSearch  == phraseArray.Length)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return allMatches.Any(wrd => wrd.Text == phraseArray[idxToSearch] && wrd.Sequence == previousWord.Sequence + 1 && NextAny(phraseArray, idxToSearch + 1, DataSet, wrd));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to find a subset:

```
public void PhraseSearch()
{
    var dataSet = new[] { "First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Five", };

    var goodSearch = new[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
    var badSearch = new[] { "First", "NOTFOUND", "Third" };

    Console.WriteLine(SubsequenceMatch(dataSet, new[] { "First", "Second", "Third" }));
    Console.WriteLine(SubsequenceMatch(dataSet, new[] { "First", "NOTFOUND", "Third" }));   
    Console.WriteLine(SubsequenceMatch(dataSet, new[] { "Second", "Third", "Forth" }));
    Console.WriteLine(SubsequenceMatch(dataSet, new[] { "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Five" }));
}

public bool SubsequenceMatch<T>(T[] source, T[] match)
{
    return
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, source.Count() - match.Count() + 1)
            .Any(n => source.Skip(n).Take(match.Count()).SequenceEqual(match));
}
```

This gives:

```
True
False
True
True
```

Comment: What if `match.Count()` is greater than `source.Count()`?

Comment: @mjwills - Ture, but this is a good starting point. It's quite a straight-forward query - easy to make more robust.